# How can I configure NiFi's DBCPConnectionPool not to keep idle connections open?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-commons-dbcp

Out of the box, NiFi (at least, as of 1.8.0), appears to keep open one database connection for each DBCPConnectionPool controller service enabled. I have multiple DBCPConnectionPool controller services configured to access the same server with different options, so this quickly adds up against a limited number of connections to my database server. I have a scheduled workflow that runs ~nightly. Connections need not be active except when in active use during a short window of time.

Looking around [DBCPConnectionPool documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html), it appears that there are *not* controller service configuration options associated with [Apache Commons-DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) `BasicDataSource` parameters like `minIdle` and `maxIdle`, which I think should be both set to 0 in my particular use case. Alternatively, I think I could set `maxConnLifetimeMillis` to something even in the minutes range and satisfy my use case (a connection need not be released *immediately* but within a reasonable period of time).

Is there a way to pass this options without modifying the DBCPConnectionPool code? Will Commons-DBCP accept these options passed as JDBC parameters by setting them as dynamic properties on a NiFi DBCPConnectionPool controller service configuration?

Comment: I am using NiFi 1.8.0 with jTDS 1.3.1 against SQL Server 2016. I looked for jTDS options governing connection liveness and found none. http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat

Comment: A nifi-users mailing list post from February 2018 seems to indicate that these BasicDataSource parameters are NOT mutatable through JDBC properties set as dynamic properties on the DBCPConnectionPool configuration. https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/9e8dec492280521bab34ffc64d016be7437f37e953b0dbd0c6039239@%3Cusers.nifi.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NiFi as of 1.8.0 [keeps one connection per database open at all times](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5789) because it uses the default configuration of Commons-DBCP 2.5.0 that does not clean up connections. The Commons-DBCP default value for `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` is `-1`, which causes idle connection eviction never to run.

NiFi *1.8.0* does not [expose the Commons-DBCP configuration options](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5790) necessary to adjust these timings.

NiFi *1.9.0* will [expose these settings, added in this commit](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/3133).